# Lego Mindstorms - Nondescript compilation Failure

Tags: compilation, lego-mindstorms, nxc

I am trying to program Lego Mindstorms robot and having a problem with NXC.
While compiling any program I get a compile error.

For example:

```
task main() {
OnFwd(OUT_A, 100);
OnFwd(OUT_C, 100);
Wait(1000);
Off(OUT_AC);
}
```

There is no error message given, just compile failed.

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: It doesn't say. Just error. Compile/download Failed. Compile failure.

Comment: This would probably be a configuration error with BricxCC. Try compliling the program with the [portable version](http://portableapps.com/node/28952) of BricxCC and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just save the file you created before compile and download.